# Bash script with fdisk

Tags: linux, bash

I came across this bash script to expand the fs after making the root volume larger on an ami made with Packer. Can someone please explain the meaning of the fdisk options in the heredoc?

```
#!/bin/bash
fdisk /dev/xvda <<EEOF
d
n
p
1
1

w
EEOF
exit 0
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document

Comment: BTW, consider sfdisk rather than fdisk for this use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not asking about the heredoc, I'm asking about the fdisk console input and it's effects. And why sfdisk?

Comment: Did you try running this command on a Linux box (just the sudo fdisk /dev/xvda part); m will show you what most of the options do; the d command deletes the partition, n creates a new one, p selects primary (vs extended), 1 selects the partition #, the 2nd 1 selects create the partition at the start of the drive, the blank uses the default, and then w writes this out to disk [do NOT do the w on a file system you care about)

Comment: As for "why sfdisk" -- `fdisk` is meant for human-driven interactive use. `sfdisk` is meant to be scripted, and capable of modifying a system's partition table to match a definition given as a stream on its stdin in a well-defined format. You're scripting; the tool built for scripting is fit-to-purpose.

Comment: ...also, `sfdisk` supports useful things like backups. Backing up a partition table before you overwrite it is, in general, a good idea. :)

Comment: Post-edit, this is indeed clearly a different question. One that running help in fdisk would answer, but a different question nonetheless.

Comment: sweet. Thanks for the rundown. Yup, I could run fdisk, and I have, but `fdisk --help` gave me switches, not these letters in the console thing. Very helpful too on the sfdisk. I'm asking here bc, well, someone often tells me more than what I could figure off the bat, and you did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine what these mean, look at the built-in help from `fdisk`. Details may differ based on your implementation; for mine, that looks like this:

```
Command (m for help): m

Help:

  DOS (MBR)
   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit nested BSD disklabel
   c   toggle the dos compatibility flag

  Generic
   d   delete a partition
   l   list known partition types
   n   add a new partition
   p   print the partition table
   t   change a partition type
   v   verify the partition table

  Misc
   m   print this menu
   u   change display/entry units
   x   extra functionality (experts only)

  Save & Exit
   w   write table to disk and exit
   q   quit without saving changes

  Create a new label
   g   create a new empty GPT partition table
   G   create a new empty SGI (IRIX) partition table
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
   s   create a new empty Sun partition table
```

...so:

- `d` deletes a partition (presumably your script was developed for a version of `fdisk` where if there's only one partition, there's no prompt over which to delete).
- `n` creates a new partition.

  - `p` indicates that it's a primary partition being created.
  - `1` indicates that it should be primary partition #1
  - `1` indicates that it should start at sector #1
  - the following blank line accepts the default end sector
- `w` writes changes to disk.

Comment: Thanks Charles! I realized during my build they were just little commands, but it threw me for a loop they weren't switches but a console kind of thing. I'm doing automated builds so it wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and adjust for your conditions:

```
#!/bin/bash

HEREDOC_VAR_1='p q ' 
echo $HEREDOC_VAR_1

HEREDOC_VAR_2='n q ' 
echo $HEREDOC_VAR_2

echo "$HEREDOC_VAR_1" | fdisk /dev/xvda
echo "$HEREDOC_VAR_2" | fdisk /dev/xvda
```

Comment: Spaces, vs newlines? I'd consider `printf -v steps '%s\n' p q` instead. And `echo "$steps"` to emit without having `echo` print everything whitespace-separated regardless.

Comment: ...lower-case variables being in line with convention; see fourth paragraph of POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: ...beyond that, though, I'm just not sure I understand what this answer adds. Is it intended to be a less harmful demonstration of how piping commands to fdisk works?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It only was example. I'll have this all recommendations are correct, Thank you.